# How to convert visual basic operator \ in C#

Tags: c#

How to convert visual basic operator \ in C# ?
I mean which is the analog of \ in C#?

```
Dim r As Integer
r = x - (5 + (x + 1) \ 6)
```

Thanks!

> Integer division is carried out using the \ Operator. Integer division
>   returns the quotient, that is, the integer that represents the number
>   of times the divisor can divide into the dividend without
>   consideration of any remainder. Both the divisor and the dividend must
>   be integral types (SByte, Byte, Short, UShort, Integer, UInteger,
>   Long, and ULong) for this operator. All other types must be converted
>   to an integral type first. The following example demonstrates integer
>   division.
>
> VB Dim k As Integer k = 23 \ 5 ' The preceding statement sets k to 4.

Comment: \ as in divide? its the same syntax in C#

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the regular division operator `/` with an integer variable.

Answer (score 4):

It is `/` in C# (though you need to care that both operands are integers).

```
int r;
r = x - (5 + (x + 1) / 6); // integer division if x is an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

It is plain `/`, as long as the operands are integral.  You'll get an integral division with the C# operator if the operands are integral.  But a decimal or floating point division if one of the operands is decimal, float or double.  If that's the case then you'll have to cast the operand to (int) or (long) to force the integral division.

Answer (score 0):

The \ operator in VB "Divides two numbers and returns an integer result."

Since C# does not have the \ operator, you cannot create one. C# version would be to cast the result as an Int surely? But in your case it will loose the precision for you, maybe with a warning as result is bound to an Int.

Could use Convert.ToInt32() where need be.

Comment: This seems like a repeat of what everyone else says but without additional content or even the solution.  Why don't they just use `/` does exactly the samething.

Comment: Zero replies when I started typing!